# Europeans expats who own an online business - how did you go about getting a USA visa?

Tags: usa, esta

I'm a EU citizen and want to live in USA for a few years.

ESTA is only for 3 months however and I'm guessing I can't just hop out of the country for a week and then return indefinitely.

I have enough savings to live comfortably in NYC/LA but don't have like $500k+ to drop on an investor visa like it's nothing. I do run a few online businesses though so maybe I can open up LLCs in USA and get a business visa of some sort?

What do you recommend or who do you recommend contacting for such problems?

Thanks! :)

Comment: While it doesn't meet your criterion of "a few years," a B-2 visa will extend the 90-day limit to a six-month limit.  Owning a company in the US should make it fairly easy to get a B-1 visa, but the duration of stay is the same as for B-2.  However, *working* for your online business while in the US would be prohibited in either status, whether your company is in the US or not.